# catkin_make not working

Tags: ros2, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having the same problem as described here https://answers.ros.org/question/258444/sudo-apt-install-catkin-not-working/ when trying to compile the Groot Graphical Editor for Ros as instructed here https://github.com/BehaviorTree/Groot

I am sourcing the ros environment with source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash although in the mentioned question it was the answer. I do have catkin installed as when I write catkin in the shell I get a clue on how to use it but when performing the sudo apt install catkin as the shell suggests after executing catkin_make fails I get the following:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 catkin : Depends: python-catkin-pkg (>= 0.4.14-2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Pd: I am using Ros2 foxy along with Ubuntu 20.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403680/catkin_make-not-working/) by [marpeja](https://answers.ros.org/users/101482/marpeja/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2022-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS 2 Foxy is using `colcon`, not `catkin` - you have to check this PR in the Groot repository:

- https://github.com/BehaviorTree/Groot/pull/119/files

There you have instructions how to build Groot in ROS 2 - you can also see my answer to this question with clear instructions how to install and use Groot to modify a BT:

- https://answers.ros.org/question/399916/i-want-to-disable-spin-and-backup-in-nav22/?answer=399943#post-id-399943

> Modification of the Behavior Tree -
> you can use the
> [Groot](https://github.com/BehaviorTree/Groot#compilation-instructions-ros).
> For the ROS2 Galactic use:
>
> ```
>    cd ~/dev_ws/src
>    git clone https://github.com/BehaviorTree/Groot.git
>    cd ..
>    rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src
>    colcon build --symlink-install --packages-select groot
> ```
>
> I have `sudo apt install ros-galactic-behaviortree-cpp-v3`
> before too.
>
> You have to `source install/setup.bash` and
> `./build/groot/Groot`.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marpeja](https://answers.ros.org/users/101482/marpeja/) on 2022-07-12**:
Thank you so much!